# GitlabCI - Multiple environments NUnit to the same build

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, nunit, gitlab-ci

Dears

My continuous integration + tests project is running with the gitlabci file on a dedicated server. Run with multiple environments is my goal to complete this project.

For example: I have two environments (desenv and homol) and my desire is build the project and after run in each one these tests changing only some variables (link, db user) in the **test-automation-inscricao-vestib.dll.config**.

I createad a yml file with 3 jobs:

- **build:test ->** nuget restore and build project
- **test:desenv ->** change file.dll.config to the respective configuration file of the environment and run testes (NUnit)
- **test:homol ->** change file.dll.config to the respective configuration file of the environment and run testes (NUnit)

Is there a way correctly to do this? Because my gitlabci-runner doesnt work fine with this configuration. E.g.:

[image: Error]

Here is my yml code:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build:test:
  only: 
   - schedules
   - web
  stage: build
  tags:
   - windows
  script:
  #Restore Nuget
   - '"C:\\Gitlab-Runner\\nuget.exe" restore "test-automation-inscricao-vestib.sln"'

  #Build project
   - '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\msbuild.exe" /t:Clean,Build /p:Configuration=Debug "test-automation-inscricao-vestib.sln"'
  artifacts:
   paths:
    - test-automation-inscricao-vestib\bin\Debug

test:desenv:
  only: 
   - schedules
   - web
  stage: test
  tags:
   - teste
  script:
  #Change the environment to DESENV
   - powershell Remove-Item test-automation-inscricao-vestib\bin\Debug\test-automation-inscricao-vestib.dll.config
   - powershell Rename-Item test-automation-inscricao-vestib\test-automation-inscricao-vestib_DESENV.dll.config test-automation-inscricao-vestib\bin\Debug\test-automation-inscricao-vestib.dll.config

  #Run tests
   - cd test-automation-inscricao-vestib/bin/Debug
   - '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" "test-automation-inscricao-vestib.dll" --where "cat==Producao"'

  dependencies:
   - build:test   


test:homol:
  only: 
   - schedules
   - web
  stage: test
  tags:
   - teste
  script:
  #Change the environment to HOMOL
   - powershell Remove-Item test-automation-inscricao-vestib\bin\Debug\test-automation-inscricao-vestib.dll.config
   - powershell Rename-Item test-automation-inscricao-vestib\test-automation-inscricao-vestib_HOMOL.dll.config test-automation-inscricao-vestib\bin\Debug\test-automation-inscricao-vestib.dll.config

  #Run tests
   - cd test-automation-inscricao-vestib/bin/Debug
   - '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" "test-automation-inscricao-vestib.dll" --where "cat==Producao"'

  dependencies:
   - build:test
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this mistake. I add some tags in each NUnit running line and it works! Look here:

Before:

```
- '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" "test-automation-inscricao-vestib.dll" --where "cat==Producao"'
```

After:

```
- '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" "test-automation-inscricao-vestib.dll" --inprocess --labels=On --where "cat==Producao"'
```

Fixed only including these tags: **--inprocess --labels=On**